# XSS - It is possible to sanitise user input by removing "<"?

Tags: javascript, xss, sanitization, html-sanitizing

On the front-end is it possible to catch all XSS attacks by removing `<` from user content? This seems a simple way to disable malicious code, and currently I have no use-cases that would require `<` to be preserved. Will this work in all cases?

The way I would display user content would always be as inner html, e.g.

```
<div>{USER CONTENT}</div>
```

Comment: You could also escape the character, depending on where you place the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends where you *use* the user input.

If you use it inside a `a href=`, then well: no!

```
<a href="{{linkFromUser}}">
```

and then that could be `javascript:alert('oh no');`

and a browser *will* execute it if the link is pressed, in the context of your page.

Comment: Yes thank you. I have updated my question to clarify my expected usage.

Comment: have a look [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Experimental_Minimal_Encoding_Rules). Make sure no UTF7 is used and also escape `&`.

Comment: Nice one. I think that answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

**To clarify, the answer is in a comment of the accepted answer**.

**Lux** kindly linked a [document](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Experimental_Minimal_Encoding_Rules) confirming that a similar approach of entity encoding `<` is enough to prevent scripts running inside inner html content (which pretty much answers my question). However `&` also needs to be encoded and the `UTF7 XSS` charset should be avoided (apparently).